# Problem with connecting Crystal Reports to SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have a problem

I am a project worker vb.net 2015 with sql

After I cleared the project and tried the project at the client

An error appears when the reports are shown by the crystal Report

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rpt As New WaznRep
    For Each DSC As CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo In rpt.DataSourceConnections
        DSC.SetLogon(muser, mpass)
        DSC.SetConnection(mserver, mdb, False)
    Next

    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    ReportV1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

whereas

mserver = server

mdb = the name of the database

muser = username sql

mpass = sql password

They are retrieved from a text file

When running the program when the client does not open the report

[image]

This message appears and the name of the database is empty

and i used anther code to connect

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim rpt1 As New WaznRep
    Dim ConInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = mserver
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = mdb
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = muser
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = mpass
    rpt1.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(ConInfo)
    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1
    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    ReportV1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

anther

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table
    Dim rpt1 As New WaznRep
    cryRpt.Load("D:\1.rpt")

    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = mserver
        .DatabaseName = mdb
        .UserID = muser
        .Password = mpass
    End With

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next
    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    ReportV1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

all code working in my PC but Not Working  in client PC

in my PC and client PC same Crystal report version

Edit----

```
 Dim rpt As New WaznRep
    For Each DSC As CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo In rpt.DataSourceConnections
        DSC.SetConnection(mserver, mdb, False)
        DSC.SetLogon(muser, mpass)

    Next
    rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(muser, mpass)

    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    ReportV1.ShowDialog()
```

when i use integrated security=false

db name not show

[image: integrated security=false]

when i use integrated security=true

```
 Dim rpt As New WaznRep
    For Each DSC As CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo In rpt.DataSourceConnections
        DSC.SetConnection(mserver, mdb, True)
        DSC.SetLogon(muser, mpass)

    Next
    rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(muser, mpass)

    ReportV1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    ReportV1.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

db name show but not work in client pc

Comment: For future reference, don't take screenshots of entire screens or entire forms when only a small part of it is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved the solution

must install the NATIVE SQL driver to get access to Crystal Reports.